# Jquery uploading file with ajax error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a text file to my server using **jquery** **ajax** and **php** this is my **jquery** code:

```
//This is inside inner method
var file = new Blob([text],{type: 'text/plain'});

var KysForm = document.querySelector("form");

var formData = new FormData(KysForm);
formData.append("Assets",file,"assets.txt");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

$.ajax({
      url: 'kys_editor.php',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
           alert(data);
     }
});
```

This is my **php** code:

```
<?php    
    include "kys_DbConnect.php";            
    $data="";           
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){          
        $data = $_POST["data"];
        $target_dir =   "Images/";        
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["Assets"]["name"]);       
        $uploadOk = 1;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Assets"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
          echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["Assets"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.".$_FILES["Assets"]["tmp_name"];
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }       
    if(isset($data)){
      $author = "Jois";
      $insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO kys_write (Author, writing) VALUES (?,?)");
      $insert->bind_param("ss",$author,$data);
      $insert->execute();
      echo "Successfully inserted".$data;
    }            
?>
```

This is my **html** code:

```
<form method="post" action="kys_editor.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" id="write" name="data"  >
 <input type="file"   accept="image/*" name="image" onchange="showImage()" id="image">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"  onclick="inner()">   
</form>
```

I dont know what the error is but i am not able to get back a response . I mean success method is never called . Can i know where i am going wrong??

Comment: data is posted properly? do you get all data in $_POST and $_FILES?

Comment: This worked file till when my $_Files[image] but when i changed it to  $_Files[Assets] it's not working

Comment: ok then change in your HTML `name="image"` to `name-"Assets"`

Comment: no i dont want to access the file in the form tag. i want to access the file in the formdata how can i do that?